# Projective space as the glue of affine schemes: checking the cocycle condition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, schemes, projective-space

One construction of projective space over a ring $A$ is to take $n+1$ affine opens given by $$ U_i = \operatorname{Spec} \frac{A\left[\frac{x_0}{x_i}, \dots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}\right]}{x_i/x_i-1},$$ and then gluing along the open sets $D(x_j/x_i)$, which admit the explicit description $$U_{ij} = \operatorname{Spec} \frac{A\left[\frac{x_0}{x_i}, \dots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}, \frac{1}{x_j/x_i}\right]}{x_i/x_i-1}.$$
We take the gluing isomorphisms $\phi_{ij}$ by sending $x_k/x_i$ to $\frac{x_k/x_j}{x_i/x_j}$ and $x_k/x_j$ to $\frac{x_k/x_i}{x_j/x_i}$.
I want to check that these isomorphisms agree on the triple intersections.

The first hint is to show the triple intersection $U_{ij} \cap U_{jk} \cap U_{ik}$ is affine.
I think the corresponding ring should look like
$$ \frac{A\left[\frac{x_0}{x_i}, \dots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}, \frac{x_0}{x_j}, \dots, \frac{x_n}{x_j}, \frac{1}{x_j/x_i}, \frac{1}{x_k/x_i}, \frac{1}{x_k/x_j}\right]}{(x_i/x_i-1, x_j/x_j-1)}.$$
Then via the gluing ismorphisms, I have $$ \frac{1}{x_j/x_i} = x_i/x_j, \\ \frac{1}{x_k/x_i} = \frac{x_i/x_j}{x_k/x_j} = x_i/x_j \cdot x_k/x_i \cdot x_i/x_j, \\ \frac{1}{x_k/x_j} = \frac{x_k/x_i}{x_j/x_i} = x_k/x_i \cdot x_i/x_j.$$
I don't believe I assume anywhere in this calculation that the cocycle condition holds. Thus the intersection should reduce to
$$ \frac{A\left[\frac{x_0}{x_i}, \dots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}, \frac{x_0}{x_j}, \dots, \frac{x_n}{x_j}\right]}{(x_i/x_i-1, x_j/x_j-1)}.$$
Since this is independent of which gluing isomorphism I use first, I'm quite sure this shows that the gluing information agrees on triple intersections, but as this is my first time working with these concepts I am not sure if it is complete. Is there a better way to see the result?

Comment: I'm not confident enough to answer your main question, but a few details seem off. First, $\frac{1}{x_k/x_i}$ should be $x_i/x_j \cdot x_j/x_k$. Second, I think your ring for the triple intersection should have a lot more relations, all the $\frac{x_t}{x_j} = \frac{x_t}{x_i} \cdot \frac{1}{x_j/x_i}$. Third, kind of nitpicking, but I think the triple intersection should be $U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k$ rather than $U_{ij} \cap U_{jk} \cap U_{ik}$, so really the ring for the triple intersection should be the one for $U_i$, adjoined $1/{x_j/x_i}, 1/{x_k/x_i}$ and some corresponding relations.

Comment: The way the assumptions of the gluing lemma is written, I thought we would want the triple intersections to be the intersections of the $U_{ij}$? Moreover since we glue along the opens $U_{ij}:= D(x_j/x_i) \subset U_i$, which is what I thought the triple overlaps would refer to.

Comment: Re: the first one, since $\frac{1}{x_k/x_i} = \frac{x_i/x_j}{x_k/x_j}$, my calculations gave me the relations I wrote in my question... Maybe I made a mistake? Although I'd guess even taking the relation you wrote doesn't change the overall argument, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You wrote $\frac{1}{x_k/x_i} = \frac{x_i/x_j}{x_k/x_j} = x_i/x_j \cdot x_k/x_i \cdot x_i/x_j$, that is a mistake (a minor one). It should be $x_i/x_j \cdot x_i/x_k \cdot x_j/x_i$.

Comment: For the triple intersection, what you currently have written is a polynomial ring with $2n+3$ generators and no relations (well, $2n+5$ generators, and the relations that two of the generators are equal to $1$). That is a coordinate ring of affine space of dimension $2n+3$, not the triple intersection you are looking for.

Comment: basically, you are right. the only problem is that you should write things a little more carefully. what  Zach saying is that if your proof is correct it should work after changing the names $X_m/X_i=Y_{mi}$. if you can rewrite your proof by this variables you can be sure that you understand the proof.(for example when you rewrite the proof with this variables you see that you need  relations of the form $Y_{mi}Y_{nj}=Y_{ni}Y_{mj}$ for defining the intersection ring which is a good thing because you use this kind of relation later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R \subset A(x_0,\dotsc,x_n)$ be the ring of rational functions with coefficients in $A$, with numerator and denominator homogeneous of the same degree. To allow non-integral domain rings $A$, let's add the restriction that denominators of elements in $R$ have to be monomials with coefficient $1$.

Then each of the open sets $U_i$ corresponds to the subring of $R$ consisting of elements with denominators that are just powers of $x_i$. This is not great notation, but let's write $R_i$ for this ring, so $R_i = \{p/q \colon \deg(p)=\deg(q), q = x_i^t\}$. So $U_i = \operatorname{Spec}(R_i)$.

Similarly, let's write $R_{ij}$ for the elements $p/q$, $q = x_i^t x_j^u$, and similarly $R_{ijk}$ for the elements whose denominator factors in powers of $x_i,x_j,x_k$.
These are subrings of $R$.
And in fact $U_{ij} = \operatorname{Spec}(R_{ij})$,
and $U_{ijk} = \operatorname{Spec}(R_{ijk})$.
More than this, the inclusion maps $U_{ijk} \subset U_{ij} \subset U_i$
correspond to the inclusions $R_i \subset R_{ij} \subset R_{ijk}$.

At this point the agreement on triple intersections (the fact that $U_{ijk} \to U_{ij} \to U_j$ agrees with $U_{ijk} \to U_{jk} \to U_j$)
is pretty immediate from the fact that the inclusion maps of rings are all compatible, $R_j \subset R_{ij} \subset R_{ijk}$ gives the same inclusion map as $R_j \subset R_{jk} \subset R_{ijk}$.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear why we have to restrict denominators to monomials of coefficient 1?

Comment: Mostly I don’t want any zero divisors of $A$ to appear in the denominators. But also, pure monomials are the denominators that appear in the rings you defined. I’m just recreating the same rings.